# Under pressure, why do some things explode and some liquify?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, phase-transition, physical-chemistry, explosions

For example, diesel under compression (heats and?) explodes; refrigerant under compression cools and turns from a gas into a liquid.

Is it just simply that different fluids behave differently under the same conditions?

Comment: Would [chemistry.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Diesel does not explode under compression, but a diesel-air mixture may.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compression of a vapour usually results in a rise in temperature (note that in [vapour-compression refrigeration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapor-compression_refrigeration)  it is not the compression that liquidises the refrigerant, it is the subsequent cooling as the hot vapour releases heat to the surroundings). If the vapour is flammable (like diesel) and if there is a source of oxygen available then the temperature rise from compression alone may be sufficient to cause ignition of the vapour, which is the principle of the diesel engine. Other forms of internal combustion engine, such as the petrol engine, require an additional source of heat such as a spark, to initiate ignition. Being flammable is an undesirable property in refrigerants (although propane was used as an early refrigerant) which is why modern fridges do not tend to go up in flames.

So the short answer is yes, it depends on the chemical composition of the gas/fluid.